# Is it possible for a properly set up MySQL to return invalid UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I am wondering: assuming everything is set up properly, meaning a column with charset `utf8mb4` and a client connecting to the database setting the connection encoding to `utf8mb4`, is there any way in which said client could `SELECT` data which contains invalid UTF-8 byte sequences? Is there any way to insert data into a `utf8mb4` column which is not in fact valid UTF-8?

Put another way: is it reasonable to assume that `SELECT`ing any non-binary column over a client connection set to `utf8mb4` should always return valid UTF-8 byte sequences?

<sub>(Let's assume plain `SELECT *` statements without any `CAST` shenanigans or such.)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't *think* so.  But I have come close:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE invalid (c VARBINARY(22));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO invalid (c) VALUES (UNHEX('65c3c3c366'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT HEX(c) FROM invalid;
+------------+
| HEX(c)     |
+------------+
| 65C3C3C366 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE invalid MODIFY COLUMN c VARCHAR(22) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                         |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xC3\xC3\xC3f' for column 'c' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT HEX(c) FROM invalid;
+--------+
| HEX(c) |
+--------+
| 65     |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

By starting with `BINARY`, then converting to `CHAR`, I can get invalid data into the column.  However, the `ALTER` gives a warning when I try to convert it.

Note in the final `SELECT`, the data is truncated.  The truncation happened in the `ALTER`, not the `SELECT`, where your Question wanted it to happen.  This can be verified by converting back to `BINARY`:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE invalid MODIFY COLUMN c VARBINARY(22);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT HEX(c) FROM invalid;
+--------+
| HEX(c) |
+--------+
| 65     |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you have seen the problem happen, please provide details; perhaps I can dissect the problem.

Comment: Well, the question originated here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48524695/476; I'm skeptical about the concrete circumstances the OP describes and suspect it's an XY problem, and it's been impossible to get details out of the OP.

Comment: Essentially you're demonstrating that a binary column can of course contain any binary gibberish you want, but as soon as you try to put that into an actual `utf8mb4` column the data will be normalised to the extent possible and be valid UTF-8 data henceforth. That's what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you´re welcome to help me to understand the problem...
In the reffered thread the data comes from a html form field und was inserted in a prepared field.
There was no data conversion after the insert!
First of all, why it happens: A Javascript tries to interpret the string U+1F601 as expression for the unicode character of the "beaming face with smiling eyes". I must left us without details but the bug was the appendix of an 'A' so U+1F601A was interpreted. After the part of the code that tests the char for a surrogate pair; "\udf98\udc1a" was left.
Now see the code below, it creates a fresh empty table, inserts the value of the textarea.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<pre><?php
    ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
    ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Berlin');
    ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
    $dbConnection = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
    $dbConnection->query("SET NAMES utf8");
    if($_POST) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
                    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `message` VARCHAR(1920) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
                )
                COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;";
        $dbConnection->query($sql);
        $char = $dbConnection->real_escape_string($_POST['hallo']);
        $sql = "SELECT HEX('".$char."')";
        echo $sql."\n";
        $result = $dbConnection->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        echo $row[0]."\n";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES (0, '".$char."');";
        $dbConnection->query($sql);

        $sql = "SELECT message FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        echo $sql."\n";
        $result = $dbConnection->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        echo $row[0]."\n";

        if(!mb_check_encoding($row[0], "UTF-8")) {
            echo "Php says its not valid\n";
        }
    }
?></pre>
<form method="post" action="test.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <textarea id="test" name="hallo" id="test"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var character = "\udf98\udc1a";
    var expression = /\\u([A-Fa-f0-9]{4}?)/gi;
    character = character.replace(expression, function(match, grp) {
        console.log("grp is " + grp);
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16));
    });

    console.log(unescape(character));
    document.getElementById('test').value = unescape(character);

    var first = "\\u" + String.fromCharCode(parseInt("df98", 16));
    var second = "\\u" + String.fromCharCode(parseInt("dc1a", 16));
    var character = first + second;
    var third = unescape(character);

    console.log(first);
    console.log(second);
    console.log(third);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you need to [merge your two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts). I think you're trying to clarify here, in which case you can also just edit your original question. Answers are only for answers, not replying, here on SE.